# Enumerate folder/subfolder contents to right-click context menu of system tray application in C#

Tags: c#, icons, directory, system, tray

I'm utilizing the template from https://alanbondo.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/creating-a-system-tray-app-with-c/ for creating a system tray icon that has a right-click context menu.

I'm able to have one of the buttons launch an explorer process that opens to the root of a directory using this function

```
    private void MyApps(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String currentUser = Environment.UserName.ToString();
        Process explorer = new Process();
        explorer.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
        explorer.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Users\" + currentUser + @"\desktop\MyApps";
        explorer.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        explorer.Start();
    }
```

What I would rather do is have the system tray icon button, when clicked, expand into a sub-menu that contains the contents of the desired directory, which itself contains browseable sub-folders.   Imagine the (pre-Windows 8) Start menu with nested menus and applications; that is the behavior I'd like to mimic.

What I have found thus far are multiple projects people have written to create their own customized Windows Explorer shell, do actually have to go that far in order to dynamically enumerate the contents of the desired folder into the right-click context menu of a system tray icon?

I'm much more comfortable using visual studio forms for .NET applications but from what I have read, there's no way to actually 'hide' the form at launch, so for now I'm using C#

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit:  Here's the updated code with the suggested method for recursively populating the menu item with the contents of the specified directory.  I'm now getting an error that  "System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem" does not contain a definition for DropDownItems

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;



namespace MyTrayApp
{
    public class SysTrayApp : Form
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new SysTrayApp());
        }

        private NotifyIcon trayIcon;
        private ContextMenu trayMenu;

        public SysTrayApp()
        {
            trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
            trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", OnExit);
            trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("My Applications").Click += new EventHandler(MyApps);

            trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            trayIcon.Text = "MyTrayApp";
            trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);

            trayIcon.ContextMenu = trayMenu;
            trayIcon.Visible = true;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            Visible = false; // Hide form window.
            ShowInTaskbar = false; // Remove from taskbar.

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        private void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                trayIcon.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        }

        private void MyApps(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String currentUser = Environment.UserName.ToString();

            string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\" + currentUser + @"\desktop\My Applications");
            foreach (string dir in directories)
            {
                string[] subdir = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
                this.trayMenu.MenuItems.Add(dir);
                foreach (string sub in subdir)
                {
                    (trayMenu.MenuItems[trayMenu.MenuItems.Count - 1] as MenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(sub); 


                }

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    this.trayMenu.MenuItems.Add(file);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It does not seem a very difficult task. You have to enumerate the subfolders using `Directory.GetDirectories` and generate the context menu using that info. But i haven't tried it, if you have and have any specific problem, ask another question about it

Comment: Is that likely to populate just a list of the contents of the desired directory, vs. being a shortcut to the files that can be single-clicked to launch the individual files directly from the list?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple quick test i've made, using a simple ContextMenuStrip. It of course should be recursive, but just to get you on the track:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\descargas");
foreach (string dir in directories)
{
     string[] subdir = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
     this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(dir);
     foreach(string sub in subdir)
     {
          (contextMenuStrip1.Items[contextMenuStrip1.Items.Count-1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(sub);
     }

     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
     foreach(string file in files)
     {
          this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(file);
     }
}
```

**Edit**

As you are using ContextMenu, and using your provided code, you should do something like this:

```
private void MyApps(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String currentUser = Environment.UserName.ToString();

        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\" + currentUser + @"\desktop\My Applications");
        foreach (string dir in directories)
        {
            string[] subdir = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
            MenuItem mi=new MenuItem(dir);
            foreach (string sub in subdir)
            {
                mi.MenuItems.Add(sub); 


            }


            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                mi.MenuItems.Add(file);
            }
            this.trayMenu.MenuItems.Add(mi);
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested it, but I think this would do more or less what you want

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. 

  I think i'm missing an include; what is the declaration that would include  DropDownItems

Comment: @gunstarone I think you are using ContextMenu. In my example, i'm using **ContextMenuStrip**. That's why you don't have `DropDownItems`