# Dynamically make ToolStripItems for ContextMenuStrip in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 folders which contains a bunch of subfolders and files. I need to create a ContextMenuStrip with all the folders and files as ToolStripMenuItems (as a tree hierarchy). I know how to hardcode it:

```
    public class CustomApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        private NotifyIcon trayIcon;
        private ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem option1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Option 1");
        ToolStripMenuItem option1a = new ToolStripMenuItem("Option 1a");
        ToolStripMenuItem option1b = new ToolStripMenuItem("Option 1b");
        ToolStripMenuItem option1c = new ToolStripMenuItem("Option 1c");
        ToolStripMenuItem option1ca = new ToolStripMenuItem("Option 1ca");
        ToolStripMenuItem option2 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Option 2");
        ToolStripMenuItem option3 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Option 3");
        ToolStripMenuItem option4 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Option 4");

        public CustomApplicationContext()
        {
            contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[]
            {
                this.option1,
                this.option2,
                this.option3,
                this.option4
            });
            this.option1.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[]
            {
                this.option1a,
                this.option1b,
                this.option1c
            });
            this.option1c.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] 
            {
                this.option1ca
            });
            trayIcon = new NotifyIcon()
            {
                Icon = Resources.AppIcon,
                ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip,
                Visible = true
            };
        }
    }
```

However, I would like to make it more dynamically so if something change within one of the folders, it'll also be dynamically changed.

How would I be able to do that?

Comment: The same way you added ToolStripMenuItems in your example code?

Comment: That isn't really helpful. I am not able or aware on how to do it and saying I need to do it in the same way, doesn't really explain anything. I'm sorry, if this is something easily done for you, but I am still very new to programming.

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example of what you want to do?  "Make it more dynamically" can mean many things.

Comment: Essentially, the 3 parentfolders contain multiple folders and .pdf files. I need to make a tree of all the folders, subfolders and files. For every folder and it's subfolder need to be a branch in the ContextMenuStrip. The reason to making it dynamic is that if someone adds a new folder or file, I want it to add it to the ContextMenu.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a [TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239544/populate-treeview-with-file-system-directory-structure) for this?

Comment: That might well be a better way to go about it. Is it something that can be added to a NotifyIcon? The reason being, that the menu has to running via the NotifyIcon

Comment: You want to put a folder listing in the tray?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36136833

Comment: Yes, I need to use tray - I'll have a look at the post you've linked. Thank you

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I use this technique for my help menus. This enables the users to add their own manuals and usage notes. The directory tree for these documents is always kept small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a recursive method that iterates through a directory tree recursively.

```cs
private static void AddMenuItemsRecusively(
    DirectoryInfo root, 
    ToolStripItemCollection itemCollection)
{
    FileInfo[] files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
    if (files != null) {
        foreach (FileInfo fi in files) {
            itemCollection.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem(fi.Name));
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs) {
            var menuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(dirInfo.Name);
            itemCollection.Add(menuItem);
            AddMenuItemsRecusively(dirInfo, menuItem.DropDownItems);
        }
    }
}
```

Since we must be able to add menu items to a `ContextMenuStrip.Items` as well as to `ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems`, we pass a `ToolStripItemCollection` to the method.

We create the menu structure like this with `baseDir` as `DirectoryInfo` containing the base directory.

```cs
AddMenuItemsRecusively(baseDir, contextMenuStrip.Items);
```

Call `contextMenuStrip.Items.Clear();` before adding the menu items if you want to populate the context menu repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does exactly what I want! So when you call the `AddMenuItemsRecusively(dirInfo, menuItem.DropDownItems);` within the method, is that what make it recurse through the folders?

Comment: Yes, the `AddMenuItemsRecusively` method calls itself with a new `DirectoryInfo` corresponding to a sub-directory and a new `ToolStripItemCollection` corresponding to a sub-menu and repeats calling itself until there are no more sub-directories in the current sub-directory. [Debug this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) and single step through it to see what happens. Search for [c# recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+recursion) to find more about this technique.